# How to get warnings for implicit conversion to bool in simple return statement from clang or clang-tidy

Tags: c, clang, clang-tidy

The question is how to get a warning for using `=` by mistake when `==` is intended.

The warning `-Wparentheses` gives warnings when implicitly converting the result of an assignment to a `bool` value in certain contexts. However, for a function that is just a simple return statement, that warning is triggered in gcc but not in clang.

In the following example, if written explicitly (-DEXPLICIT) both clang and gcc gives a warning, but for the shorter `return *x = *y;` gcc gives a warning (with `-std=c99 -Wall`) but clang does not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool is_equal(int *x, int *y)
{
#ifdef EXPLICIT
    if(*x = *y) return true;
    else return false;
#else
    return *x = *y;
#endif
}

int main()
{
    int foo = 17;
    int bar = 42;

    bool b = is_equal(&foo, &bar);

    printf("%d %s %d\n", foo, (b?" == ":" != "), bar);
}
```

(Here, the intended result of `is_equal` is an equality test, so the assignment is a bug. *Please note that this is a minimal example: for a simple equality test the pointers should be `const` and thus catch the accidental assignment, but in the actual code that motivated this question they couldn't be.*)

I also hoped that the clang-tidy check `readability-implicit-bool-conversion` would trigger, but it doesn't.

(**Update:** Clang gives no warning (related to this) with `-Weverything`, but can I get clang-tidy to warn about this?)

Is there a way to get clang or clang-tidy to warn for this int-to-bool conversion?

I know it is not "dangerous" in the sense that it is well-defined and portable and that it may be common in existing code, but it is still a potential bug I want to be able to check for.

Comment: `return *x = *y;` should be `return *x == *y;`, as well as `if(*x = *y)` should be `if(*x == *y)`

Comment: @KfirVentura I think OP really wants it to be an assignment

Comment: The assignment is a bug, it should be equality check.

Comment: @drRobertz Then update the question...

Comment: done. I hoped the name is_equal was clear enough, but updated.

Comment: @drRobertz You want the code to be with an assignment and then have clang to give you a warning, right? I think you need to explain that better. Soon you will get answers telling you to use `==` instead but that's not what you are asking, I assume

Comment: You might expect too much from GCC or Clang, as you say, the expression is well defined. Did you try all options concerning code quality? You might like to use a specialized tool for this that checks conformance to your programming rules.

Comment: @thebusybee That is why I asked about clang-tidy. The documentation has a similar example, but I cannot  get that to work.
Also, gcc does give the warning, but I would like it from clang as well.

Answer (score -1):

`*x = *y`: I think you wanted this to be an equality check, but it is currently an assignment. Change it to `*x == *y`, here `if(*x = *y) return true;` and here `return *x = *y;`.

I would also recommend changing the function signature to `bool is_equal(const int *x, const int *y)` to make it clear that the function shall not change the inputs.

Comment: Thank you, these are good suggestions, but this is a minimal example. In the actual code where this just bit me they cannot be const.

Comment: I saw you edited your question. So what you actually want is for the `EXPLICIT` variant to trigger a warning.

Comment: No, the EXPLICIT bit triggers -Wparentheses in both clang and gcc, but the simple return statement doesn't in clang. The question is if it is possible to get clang to warn for this kind of accidental assignments.